# How can i convert a const mat image into an Iplimage?

Tags: opencv, mat

i'm working on the extraction of an algorithm from a source existing library. Inside a function there is a declaration of IplImage initialized with a Const cv::mat :

```
IplImage *frame = new IplImage(img_input);
```

compiling i get the following error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘_IplImage::_IplImage(const cv::Mat&)
```

I think this is because the library uses an old version of opencv. So the question is how can i get the same result in the new version of opencv?(i'm using the latest)

Comment: By converting the existing library to use `cv::Mat`. Support for `IplImage` has been removed.